# How to export all the Details in the Div using Beautiful soup python to excel/csv?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

i am Newbie to Soup/python and i am trying to find the data.
my website Structure look like this.
[image]

and if i open the Divclass `border class` it look like this.(image below)

I have done something like this:

```
for  P in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'bid_no pull-left'}) :
  print(P.find('a').contents[0])
```

[image]

a Div structure look like
 there are around 10 div in each page
this in which i want to extract the **Items,Quantity Require,Bid number,End date**.
Please help me

```
<div class="border block " style="display: block;">
    <div class="block_header">
        <p class="bid_no pull-left"> BID NO: <a style="color:#fff !important" href="/showbidDocument/1844736">GEM/2020/B/763154</a></p> 
        <p class="pull-right view_corrigendum" data-bid="1844736" style="display:none; margin-left: 10px;"><a href="#">View Corrigendum</a></p>

         <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-block">
        <p><strong style="text-transform: none !important;">Item(s): </strong><span>Compatible Cartridge</span></p>
        <p><strong>Quantity Required: </strong><span>8</span></p>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-block">
        <p><strong>Department Name And Address:</strong></p>
        <p class="add-height">
            Ministry Of Railways<br> Na<br> South Central Railway N/a
        </p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-block">
        <p><strong>Start Date: </strong><span>25-08-2020 02:54 PM</span></p>
        <p><strong>End Date: </strong><span>04-09-2020 03:00 PM</span></p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>


    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Error image

[image: Error]
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have tried something then please post it here first then only someone will be able to help you in this regard also your question description is to vague and very hard to understand most important Add website URL.

Comment: https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists @Vin

Comment: i a not able to find the Text withing the same class "col-block" @Vin pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) and **beautiful soup**. I have created the script with the URL which is fetched from website and then creating a dynamic URL to traverse each and every page to get the data.

What exactly script is doing:

1. First script will create a URL where **page_no** query string parameter will increment by 1 upon completion of each traversal.
2. Requests will get the data from the created URL using **get** method which will then pass to beautiful soup to parse HTML structure using **lxml**.
3. Then from the parsed data script will search for the **div** where data is actually present.
4. Finally looping on all the **div** text data one by one for each page.

   ````
   ```python
   import requests
   from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
   requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

   def scrap_bid_data():

   page_no = 1 #initial page number
   while True:
       print('Hold on creating URL to fetch data...')
       URL = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + str(page_no) #create dynamic URL
       print('URL cerated: ' + URL)

       scraped_data = requests.get(URL,verify=False) # request to get the data
       soup_data = bs(scraped_data.text, 'lxml') #parse the scraped data using lxml
       extracted_data = soup_data.find('div',{'id':'pagi_content'}) #find divs which contains required data

       if len(extracted_data) == 0: # **if block** which will check the length of extracted_data if it is 0 then quit and stop the further execution of script.
           break
       else:
           for idx in range(len(extracted_data)): # loops through all the divs and extract and print data
               if(idx % 2 == 1): #get data from odd indexes only because we have required data on odd indexes
                   bid_data = extracted_data.contents[idx].text.strip().split('\n')
                   print('-' * 100)
                   print(bid_data[0]) #BID number
                   print(bid_data[5]) #Items
                   print(bid_data[6]) #Quantitiy Required
                   print(bid_data[10] + bid_data[12].strip()) #Department name and address
                   print(bid_data[16]) #Start date
                   print(bid_data[17]) #End date                   
                   print('-' * 100)

           page_no +=1 #increments the page number by 1

    scrap_bid_data()
    ```
   ````

> Actual Code

[image]

> Output image

[image]

Comment: GETTING THE ERROR    URL = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + str(page_no)  # create dynamic URL
NameError: name 'page_no' is not defined

Comment: It is working at my end make sure your code is indented properly and all the imports are available for your reference i have added an output image as well.

Comment: i am using pycharm

Comment: it doesn't matter which IDE you are using just make sure you have aligned the code properly with all the imports mentioned in the code itself

Comment: i have added the Image of the error in Question pls see

Comment: Add an image of full code as well which you have pasted.

Comment: As I can see you have messed up the whole code and like I have mentioned code indentation is really poor that’s why it is giving an error. Align the code under page_no = 1 is written

Comment: it worked But i am getting 1st page data  then 11 page then 21 why is that ?

Comment: Added actual code image check line by line and see where you have done the mistakes. Once it will start working for you mark it as accepted.Thanks

Comment: it's working now but i am getting 1,10,21,31,41,51.......pages data i want every page data.

Comment: Check image which i have just uploaded and compare with your code. I'm damn sure you have done some more mistakes because it is working at my end flawlessly and as expected. I would suggest you to check each line of image with yours.

Comment: i am still getting page no 1,11,21,31........data i want all pages data

Comment: worked now pls tell me how to Import them to excel/csv